# How can I use the private class in android os?

Tags: android, calendar, private-class

I have just downloaded the source code of Google calendar.But in the project,some private classes,such as `android.provider.Calendar`, are included.How can I import such classes?

Answer (score 1):

> How can I import such classes?

**You don't.** That's the point of them being `private`: they are not meant for you to use.

Solve your problem some other way.